# Window.onpopstate it's activated with all href links

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm implementing a pagination using jQuery ajax but manipulating the history of the browser, and works fine so far but I realized a few hours ago that if I have a link in any part of my page:

```
<a href="#">My link</a>
```

And make a click on this link, the function `window.onpopstate` is called but I don't know why, and this happens with all A HREF of my website.

This is my function, detecting the current state to call to specific functions and load data by country or search term or the parameter of the URL specified.

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    var section = $('#wrapper section').attr('id');

    if(event && event.state) {

        
        //State for Reviews pagination ?page=x
        if (event.state.type == 'pagination') {
            popStateShopPage(event.state);
        }

        //State for Reviews pagination by country ?country=MX&page=x
        if (event.state.type == 'country') {
            popStateShopPageCountry(event.state);
        }

        //State for Reviews pagination by search ?search=hello&page=x
        if (event.state.type == 'search') {
            popStateShopPageSearch(event.state);
        }
        
    } else {

        if (section == 'shop-page') {
            popStateShopPage(1);
        }

        history.pushState(null);
    }
}
```

And I'm using these functions to push the state:

```
history.pushState({type: 'pagination', page: number_page}, "", "?page="+number_page);
history.pushState({type: 'country', page: number_page, country: country}, "", "?country="+country+"&page="+number_page);
history.pushState({type: 'search', page: number_page, term: term}, "", "?search="+term+"&page="+number_page);
```

Comment: Well, that's what `window.onpopstate` does, it fires whenever the URL changes (or more correctly the history), that includes clicking on anchors ?

Comment: I see, this is the first time I use this event... do you know any way to avoid this or a trick or something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it is stated in [MSDN Mozilla Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate):

> 1.The popstate event is fired when the active history entry changes. If
>   the history entry being activated was created by a call to
>   history.pushState() or was affected by a call to
>   history.replaceState(), the popstate event's state property contains a
>   copy of the history entry's state object.
>
> 2.Note that just calling history.pushState() or history.replaceState()
>   won't trigger a popstate event. The popstate event is only triggered
>   by doing a browser action such as a click on the back button (or
>   calling history.back() in JavaScript).

The reason window.onpopstate fires is because, first, the history has been changed when you click on the anchor tag; and second, you are doing a browser action.

In my opinion nothing can be done to avoid this, as it is stated in [JavaScritp The Definitive Guide](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch19_02.htm):

> Some events cause an associated default action to be performed by the
>   web browser. For example, when a click event occurs on an  tag, the
>   browser's default action is to follow the hyperlink. Default actions
>   like these are performed only after all three phases of event
>   propagation complete, and any of the handlers invoked during event
>   propagation have the opportunity to prevent the default action from
>   occurring by calling the preventDefault( ) method of the Event object.

The three phases are: capturing, targeting and bubbling.

Hope it's useful!

Comment: Thanks for the information, now I'm adding functions to every href within my page or change the href to btn to avoid this.

Comment: @Academia I find it confusing that you say "nothing can be done to avoid this", and at the same time you propose a working solution :)

As you quoted, just need to attach a click event handler and prevent default behaviour :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend detection of hash tag in popstate listener:

```
addEventListener('popstate', (event) => {
            if (document.location.hash !== "") return;
            else doWhatEverYouWant();
        })
```

Otherwise, If using prevent default, you have to handle history pushing again.